# Can you help me fix this youtube rss feed?

Tags: php, youtube, rss

So far what i have been trying to do is output a video response i know it wont work if i dont have the $id after the tag but before the tag it wont even work if the str_replace doesn't work.

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=Fliberjig1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
$id = $xml->entry[$i]->id;
$id = str_replace("YT:VIDEO:","", $id);
$title = $xml->entry[$i]->title;
 $html .= "<li><h3>$title</h3>
<p>$id</p>
<iframe width='854' height='480' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/$id' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></li>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

the result will be like this

> YT:VIDEO:WOCIEMNSI4C

but i want it to be like this

> WOCIEMNSI4C

Can you please help in any way to help me with my problem

Comment: It seems that `yt:video:` is in lower case so you can use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.str-ireplace.php) instead of `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to parse the string. This can be done using:

`$pieces = explode(":", $id);
$clean_id = $pieces[2];`

Comment: i found out a way to do it in one line i used a substr and just got the id pulled out of it to export it to use for the videos.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the feed contains `yt:video:WOCIemNSI4c` and not `YT:VIDEO:WOCIEMNSI4C` so what you actually need is the [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.str-ireplace.php)
function instead of [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.str-replace.php) you're currently using.

So if you change your 7th line of code to this:

```
$id = str_ireplace("YT:VIDEO:","", $id);
```

you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = "YT:VIDEO:WOCIEMNSI4C";
$rest = substr("$id", -11); //result WOCIEMNSI4C
```